# ie9 issue with replacing iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

We are currently developing a site for a client that we've been told has ie9 use but very strict on the requirements.

For this is having 4 placeholder images, when clicked on will open an iframe, and replace the iframe with a different video if clicked.

Simple enough to implement for our uses in modern browsers, the issue I'm having is the page sits and reloads in ie9 and doesn't open any of the iframes when being clicked on. (the code is pretty rough but the timeframe for this by the client was <1 hour and the other developer did it pretty much sitting next to a client in a meeting, and it works)

JS

```
 if ( $('#videoLinksMain').length ) {
    //          //switch out video placeholder with video
                function playVideo2(){
                    thevid=document.getElementById('thevideo'); 
                    thevid.style.display='block'; 
                    this.style.display='none';
                }
                            //click
                $('#videoLink1').click(function(){
                                console.log("clicked videoLink1");
                                var videoSRC = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/videolink?rel=0&autoplay=1"
                                var thevid=document.getElementById('thevideo');
                                $(thevid).slideDown(function() {
                                    $("#ytVideo")[0].src = videoSRC + "&autoplay=1";
                                });
                });
                            $('#videoLink2').click(function(){
                                console.log("clicked videoLink2");
                                var videoSRC = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/videolink?rel=0&autoplay=1"
                                var thevid=document.getElementById('thevideo');
                                $(thevid).slideDown(function() {
                                    $("#ytVideo")[0].src = videoSRC + "&autoplay=1";
                                });
                });
                            $('#videoLink3').click(function(){
                                console.log("clicked videoLink3");
                                var videoSRC = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/videolink?rel=0&autoplay=1"
                                var thevid=document.getElementById('thevideo');
                                $(thevid).slideDown(function() {
                                    $("#ytVideo")[0].src = videoSRC + "&autoplay=1";
                                });
                });
                            $('#videoLink4').click(function(){
                                console.log("clicked videoLink4");
                                var videoSRC = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/videolink?rel=0&autoplay=1"
                                var thevid=document.getElementById('thevideo');
                                $(thevid).slideDown(function() {
                                    $("#ytVideo")[0].src = videoSRC + "&autoplay=1";
                                });
                });
                            //hover
                            $('#videoLink1').hover(
                                function(){
                                    $text = "";
                                    $('#videoDesc p').replaceWith("<p>" + $text + "</p>");
                                    $('#videoDesc p').fadeIn("slow");
                                },function(){
                                    $('#videoDesc p').fadeOut();
                                }
                            );
                            $('#videoLink2').hover(
                                function(){
                                    $text = "";
                                    $('#videoDesc p').replaceWith("<p>" + $text + "</p>");
                                    $('#videoDesc p').fadeIn("slow");
                                },function(){
                                    $('#videoDesc p').fadeOut();
                                }
                            );
                            $('#videoLink3').hover(
                                function(){
                                    $text = "";
                                    $('#videoDesc p').replaceWith("<p>" + $text + "</p>");
                                    $('#videoDesc p').fadeIn("slow");
                                },function(){
                                    $('#videoDesc p').fadeOut();
                                }
                            );
                            $('#videoLink4').hover(
                                function(){
                                    $text = "";
                                    $('#videoDesc p').replaceWith("<p>" + $text + "</p>");
                                    $('#videoDesc p').fadeIn("slow");
                                },function(){
                                    $('#videoDesc p').fadeOut();
                                }
                            );
            }//end .length
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-4 " id="videoLinksMain">
                            <div class="row">
                                <!--<img src="images/play-button-light-blue.png" class="img-responsive btnPlaySml">-->
                               <!-- <img src="images/vtLink-placeholder-2.png" class="img-responsive" id="videoLink1"> -->
                               <a href="#thevideo" onclick="loadFrame(this)" target="_top" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videolink?rel=0&autoplay=1"><img src="images/vtLink-placeholder-2.png" class="img-responsive" id="videoLink1"></a> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="row margin-top-half" id="videoLinksThumbs">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <!--<img src="images/play-button-light-blue.png" class="img-responsive btnPlayTbn">-->
                                    <a href="#thevideo" onclick="loadFrame(this)" target="_top" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videolink?rel=0&autoplay=1"><img src="images/vtLink-placeholder-1.png" class="img-responsive" id="videoLink2"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <a href="#thevideo" onclick="loadFrame(this)" target="_top" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videolink?rel=0&autoplay=1"><img src="images/vtLink-placeholder-3.png" class="img-responsive" id="videoLink3"></a>
                                    <!-- <img src="images/vtLink-placeholder-3.png" class="img-responsive" id="videoLink3"> -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                   <!-- <img src="images/vtLink-placeholder-4.png" class="img-responsive" id="videoLink4"> -->
                                <a href="#thevideo" onclick="loadFrame(this)" target="_top" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videolink?rel=0&autoplay=1"><img src="images/vtLink-placeholder-4.png" class="img-responsive" id="videoLink4"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row text-center" id="videoDesc">                                
                                <p style="display:none;">This text is here to help give a textual description of each video</p>
                            </div>
```

Comment: This code needs some serious refactorization, that's for sure! And mixing some jq methods with plain javascript ones doesn't make sense

Comment: Yep. Unfortunately, the code works and other tasks can't give me a reason to change this heavily simply for internet explorer 9 functionality...harsh reality! If I was to fix it up and it still wasn't to work in ie9 then the time spans would be far too tight. Seems like the problem is with how ie handles the DOM and looks at the levels...but I'm not sure how to give priority.